# Remove extra margin in text components

Tags: html, css

This is something so simple but is giving me a big headache: how do I remove the top and bottom margin that seem to be automatically added in HTML text components?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1 style="background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px">Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Essentially the parts I marked in black on the top and bottom here:

[image]

Comment: just add line-height , try like below.

Comment: That isn't a "margin". It's part of space needed to display all letters correctly, for example, letters with descenders (pqgy) and capital letters with accents (ÄÉÑ). It's not a good idea to "remove" that space which using `line-height` will do. What you want to do isn't really possible with CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try below code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
  <body>
    <h1 style="background-color: red; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;line-height: 0.8;">Hello World!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add something like this the start/top of your CSS file

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

If you ever wonder where I copied the above code, it's from stackoverflow css
[image]